# LSTNet RuntimeError: Input and parameter tensors are not at the same device

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I cloned a [github repo](https://github.com/gokulkarthik/LSTNet.pytorch/blob/master/LSTNet-For-Cryptocurrency-Market-Prediction.ipynb) which runs a pytorch deep learning module, I customized this part to send the module and the data into GPU.

```py
train_dataset = MarketDataset(train_data, history_len=history_len)
train_data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = LSTNet()
model.to("cuda")

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=weight_decay)

train_loss_list = []
for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):
    
    epoch_loss_train = 0
    for i, batch in tqdm(enumerate(train_data_loader, start=1), 
                         leave=False, desc="Train", total=len(train_data_loader)):
            
        X, Y = batch
        X = X.to("cuda")
        Y = Y.to("cuda")
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        Y_pred = model(X)
        loss = criterion(Y_pred, Y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        with open(root_dir / 'Log/Running-Loss.txt', 'a+') as file:
            file.write(f'{loss.item()}\n')
        epoch_loss_train += loss.item()
        
    epoch_loss_train = epoch_loss_train / len(train_data_loader)
    train_loss_list.append(epoch_loss_train)
    
    with open(root_dir / 'Log/Epoch-Loss.txt', 'a+') as file:
        file.write(f'{epoch_loss_train}\n')
```

But I got this error instead

`RuntimeError: Input and parameter tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and parameter tensor at cpu`

If I checked, both the module and the X and Y is already on cuda. Why the error still indicates the input and parameters are not at the same device?

Answer (score 0):

check the parameter one by one.

```
for i in model.parameters():
    kk = i.device
    assert kk==torch.device('cuda')
```

or

```
for i in model.parameters():
    i = i.to(device)
```

Comment: I did this, but just checking, so I didn't assert them, only printing. All of them returned "cuda: 0". And running your code gave `AssertionError: `

Comment: send to cuda one by one

Comment: I tried your suggestion in 2 different ways: 1) removing the `model.to(cuda)`  and move the parameter manually with for loop. This results in `RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same`.

Comment: 2) Not changing the code, then add the for loop to move the model's parameter to cuda, this results in `RuntimeError: Input and parameter tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and parameter tensor at cpu`

Comment: But is it really the problem? because when I check where the parameters are, they all are already on cuda just by `model.to(device)`, I don't think "manually" transfer them with for loop will do the trick...

Comment: the network LSTNet, some parameters is not transfered to cuda.